# How to resolve "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Foo' operands"?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I created a class Foo as follows:

```
class Foo{

    var randomeVar:String?

    func saySomething(){
        print("Something")
    }
}
```

I now want to compare different instances of foo as follows:

```
let foo1 = Foo()
let foo2 = Foo()
if foo1 == foo2{
    print("Cool")
}
```

When I do so however the complies complaints that "Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Foo' operands". What is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you want to check? If you just want to know if they are the same instance, then use the identity operator `===`. If you want to check for equality, then conform `Foo` to `Equatable`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foo has no parent class that has any properties to perform comparison, so it has no idea how to compare itself.

Instead you need to adopt the Equatable protocol, which will then tell you to include the `==` operator, at which point you would define your action:

Your other option is to use ===, which will compare the references, so the only way this will pass is both items are pointing to the same instance.

```
class Foo : Equatable{

    var randomeVar:String?

    func saySomething(){
        print("Something")
    }

    static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool
    {
      //what makes us equal
    }
}
```

Comment: `func ==` should be `static`. And if you are going to make a class `Equatable`, add the `hashValue` method and make the class `Hashable`. Then you can put `Foo` instances in dictionaries and other collections that require `Hashable`.

Comment: @rmaddy did they change this?  I do not remember having to make it static.  Yes if the goal is to make it useful for other things then I agree, go with `Hashable`, but not everything needs to be `Hashable`, so for simplicity I went with `Equatable` (and saw others did as well as soon as I finished typing it LOL)

Comment: According to the documentation for `Equatable`, it should be `static`. Makes sense since it needs to be a type method, not an instance method.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon See [SE-0091](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0091-improving-operators-in-protocols.md) regarding the change of being able to implement protocol operator requirements with type methods (previously this was only allowed by implementing a global function). Although you cannot use `Self` for the argument types, you need to use the type `Foo`.

Comment: yeah lol, damn these swift upgrades, that's what I get for typing off of memory

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Not sure what you mean – you couldn't use `Self` as the argument type for a method pre-Swift 3 either ;)

Comment: `Instead you need to assign it the Equatable protocol` — that don't sound right, you are implementing protocol here(or conform class to protocol, IIRC is proper way to name this in ObjC), and protocol is not a `parent class`.

Comment: @user28434 I changed terminology,  I used adopt instead of assign, I can see it being confusing to some,  I never said protocols are parent classes,  I am saying that Foo has no parent class, so it has no way to know how to compare,  I fixed the language on that as well thank you.

Comment: @rmaddy, I looked at my code,  I wrote the func == outside of the class,  that is why I didnt need static, thanks again for clarification, Hamish, I also checked my code, I use Self in my protocols, that is why I was getting confused, thank you for clarification as well

Answer (score 3):

Objects are not comparable by default. You will need to write the method that compares 2 objects. Something like this:

```
func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
    return lhs.someVar == rhs.someVar
}
```

This defines the `==` function for comparing 2 Foo objects based on their variable `someVar`.

Comment: Besides adding that function, you should also have the `Foo` class conform to the `Equatable` protocol. Better yet would be to conform to `Hashable`.